# In my js file for testing .I call a send transaction to the smart contract, so what is the difference between value and gas :

Tags: solidity, web3js

```
it("allows a manager to make a payment request f(createRequest) ", async ()=> {
        await campaign.methods.createRequest('buy beer', accounts[2], '100').send({
            from: accounts[0],
            gas: '1000000'
        });
it('Contribute money from another account & checks whether it is approved or not', async () =>{
        await campaign.methods.contribute().send({
            from: accounts[1],
            value: '200'
        });
```

I want to know deciding factors, when to use gas and when to use value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is the amount of the native token that you send with the transaction.

| Network | Native token |
| --- | --- |
| Ethereum | ETH |
| Binance Smart Chain | BNB |
| Tron | TRX |

It's expressed in the smallest non-divisible unit. In case of ETH, that's wei. 1 ETH is 10^18 wei.

So as per your example, when you set the `value` to `200`, you're going to send along 0.0000000000000002 ETH to the contract with the execution of the `contribute()` function.

An example use of the `value` is when a contract wants to sell you a token for 0.1 ETH. In this case, you set the `value` to 0.1 ETH while executing the contract's `buy()` function.

**The `value` does NOT replace the `gas` fee:**

---

`gas` is the amount of the fee that you send along with the transaction. For better explanation, what gas is, there's a [great post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas) on the Ethereum StackExchange.

But in short - gas is a way of payment for the execution of the smart contract function.

The minimal amount of `gas` required to execute the function can be usually calculated using the web3 [estimateGas()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas) method (there are some exceptions when the estimate is incorrect or impossible to calculate).

Depending on the `gasPrice` (that's either calculated automatically from recent data or you can overwrite it manually), the total transaction fee is calculated in the native token (e.g. ETH).